# return valid date when two cells are compared

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to set up a dated workflow in excel, I have two alternate processes that combine into one point for completion of the process. Only one of the two processes will be used in any one project. So where the two processes combine I want a cell that looks at the two potential output dates and uses the one that has a date in it while the other is blank. I thought I could use something like 
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D20),ISBLANK(D33),D33,D20)) so if D20 is blank then print D33 or visa versa. This does not work, hence the question
Thanks for any help

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what is the output?

Comment: The formula doesn't do what you're looking for. I'm not sure if this the problem, but try `IF(ISBLANK(D20), D33, D20)`. The `OR()` will cause D33 to be used all the time if one of them is always empty.

Comment: Thanks Michael, simple and effective, it works

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D20), D33, D20)
```

Courtesy [Michael Flanakin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912643/michael-flanakin).

Answer (score 0):

Possible shorter solution:

```
=MAX(D20,D33)
```